# Calculate the grade of students in sql server 2008

Tags: sql-server-2008

For the following table

```
SQL> create table stud( sno int primary key, sname char(15), sub1 int,sub2 int, sub3 int,grade char(15));
SQL> insert into stud values(1,'Pray',98,94,90,' ');
SQL> insert into stud values(2,'Jay',57,74,40,' ');
SQL> insert into stud values(3,'Prisha',58,54,50,' ');
SQL> insert into stud values(4,'Masum',48,44,40,' ');
SQL> insert into stud values(5,'Shyam',40,40,40,' ');
```

The output of `select * from stud;` gives

```
SNO   SNAME              SUB1       SUB2       SUB3    GRADE
----- --------------- ---------- ---------- ---------- ---------------
1     Pray                98         94         90       
2     Jay                 57         74         40       
3     Prisha              58         54         50       
4     Masum               48         44         40       
5     Shyam               40         40         40
```

Can the output, in this format, give automatically which students pass or fail?
select  *  from stud;

```
SNO   SNAME              SUB1       SUB2       SUB3    GRADE
----- --------------- ---------- ---------- ---------- ---------------
1     Pray                98         94         90      Distinction
2     Jay                 57         74         40      Pass
3     Prisha              58         54         50      Pass
4     Masum               48         44         40      Fail
5     Shyam               40         40         40      Fail
```

Comment: Can you clarify the requirements for distinction, pass and fail? For example, over 90, over 50 and less than 50. And is it the average value that has to satisfy that, or all subjects at the same time?

Answer (score 0):

You can do the following :

```
SELECT SNO
,SNAME
,SUB1
,SUB2
,SUB3
,CASE 
    WHEN SUB1 < 50
        OR SUB2 < 50
        OR SUB3 < 50
        THEN 'Fail'
    WHEN (
            SUB1 BETWEEN 50
                AND 70
            )
        OR (
            SUB2 BETWEEN 50
                AND 70
            )
        OR (
            SUB3 BETWEEN 50
                AND 70
            )
        THEN 'Pass'
    WHEN SUB1 >= 70
        OR SUB2 >= 70
        OR SUB3 >= 70
        THEN 'Distinction'
    END AS GRADE
FROM STUD
```

You can use the same logic to update the grade column.

Answer (score 0):

I am not entirely sure what you want, but I would go with something like this:

```
select SNO, SNAME, SUB1, SUB2, SUB3, GRADE =
case when (sub1 + sub2 + sub3)/3 >= 90 then 'Distinction'
     when (sub1 + sub2 + sub3)/3 < 50 then 'Fail'
     else 'Pass'
end
from stud;
```

Comment: I'm not sure about the limits (90 and 50) so they would have to be changed accordingly.